# Get Share Sizes from list of Windows Servers in Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, smb

This is the code I'm working with, I made some modifications to try to make it work in modern PowerShell 7, however, it is not working.

```
$servers = @("fileserver0", "fileserver1")
$sizes | 
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq '__Total__' } | 
  Select-Object Server,@{L='Size in MB'; E={$_.TotalSize/1mb}},@{L='Size in GB'; E={$_.TotalSize/1gb}}
foreach($server in $servers) {
  write-host "Server: $server"
  $serverSizes = @(Get-CimInstance -class Win32_Share -ComputerName $server -filter "Type = 0" | 
    ForEach-Object { 
      write-host " share: $($_.Name)"
      $s = Get-ChildItem \\$server\$($_.Name) -recurse -force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum
      New-Object PSObject -property @{Name=$_.Name; Server=$server; TotalSize=$s.Sum } 
    })
  if ($serverSizes) {
     $totalServerSize = $serverSizes | Measure-Object -Property TotalSize -Sum
     $serverSizes += New-Object PSObject -property @{Name="__Total__"; Server=$server; TotalSize=$totalServerSize.Sum } 
     $sizes += $serverSizes
  }
}
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: I get a list of the servers names and the share names but no size of data on share listed.